# Or statement in switch/case ?

Tags: android, switch-statement, case

Is it possible to use an OR statement in a switch/case structure? Suppose I want to do the same thing when clicking on two different items.

I tried

```
(case R.id.bOne || case R.id.tvOne):
```

and

```
case (R.id.bOne || R.id.tvOne):
```

But none of them seem to work..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will work:

```
case R.id.bOne:
case R.id.tvOne:
  // do your stuff
```

Comment: Damn, that simple? :) Thanks man! I'll accept it if time is passed :)

Comment: @MatthiasVanb you have two answers, both of which are correct. Please accept one.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
switch(id){
    case R.id.bOne:
    case R.id.tvOne:
        // do your stuff here
        break;
    case R.id.x:
        // do your stuff here
        break;
    default:
        // do your stuff here
}
```